# How to count number of distinct ID's where status does not match

Tags: count, teradata, distinct, multiple-conditions

I have a dataset that looks similar to the below:

[image: Sample Table]

I would like to count the total number of distinct ID's that have both a 'SEND' and 'REC'. In other words, where the status does not match (values are limited to SEND and REC for Status field). In this case, the desired query would return a value of 2 since there are 2 distinct ID's that have both a 'SEND' and 'REC' in the dataset.

I tried the following query but did not work since there could only be one status per row and this query is looking for both of those status' within one row.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN '2022-01-19' AND '2022-01-19' AND Status = 'SEND' AND Status = 'REC' ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only two distinct values the most efficient way is probably:

```
select count(*)
from
 (
   SELECT ID 
   FROM Table 
   WHERE Date BETWEEN '2022-01-19' AND '2022-01-19' 
     AND Status IN ('SEND','REC')    -- only two possible values per id
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING MIN(Status) <> Max(Status) -- both values exist
 ) as dt ;
```

Comment: It seems like this worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE status = 'SEND' INTERSECT SELECT ID FROM table WHERE status = 'REC')
```

Comment: No DISTINCT needed, INTERSECT already returns unique ids